# Multiple spring context during single test execution problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have the interface and 2 implementations, that instantiated according to the property value.

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "stitching", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
    public LastEventProvider noStitchingLastEventProvider() {
        return new NoStitchingLastEventProvider();
    }
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "stitching", havingValue = "true")
    public LastEventProvider withStitchingLastEventProvider() {
            return new WithStitchingLastEventProvider();
    }
```

There are test classes that uses `stitching=true`, and there are classes that uses `stitching=false`
When I run the test classes separately, there is no problem. When I run all the test classes, one test method fails. In the logs of the failed test I see very strange behavior:
In the start of the test according to my logs, I see that the test method uses the second instance , and in the end of the test it uses the first one!!!

```
context: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2e1e02b8, started on Tue Feb 16 14:12:00 IST 2021, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@237cd4e5
14:12:30.256 [test-map-updater-status--test-0-C-1] TRACE c.m.m.s.a.WithStitchingLastEventProvider bla-bla
.
.
context: springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@348d18a3, started on Tue Feb 16 14:09:51 IST 2021, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7da10b5b
14:12:33.212 [test-map-updater-status--test-0-C-1] TRACE c.m.m.s.a.NoStitchingLastEventProvider - a-bla
```

I logged the applicationContext object before using LastEventProvider and saw that during test there was 2 different application contexts!!
This is most strange problem that I saw during 12 years using spring.
Any ideas?
Spring boot version is 2.2.2.RELEASE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are those tests in the same test class? Perhaps adding `@DirtiesContext` might help you out as it will re-create the Spring context

Comment: There are multiple test classes and multiple tests in each test class. @DirtiesContext
doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem, but I implemented the workaround: I tagged all test classes with junit5 @Tag annotation (@Tag("withStitching") and @Tag("noStitching")), created 2 maven profiles and run the tests as separated steps in my build.